# Access SQL Query: Replacing a specific number with a word

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a column that displays the language within a table as a number. I'm looking to replace these numbers to display English and French instead of 1 and 2.

For example, my table is:

| Employee_ID | First Name | Last Name | Language |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jane | Doe | 1 |
| 2 | John | Smith | 1 |
| 3 | Alice | Cooper | 2 |

And I want to convert the Language from 1 to display English and 2 to display French.

My current query is:

```
SELECT E.employee_ID, E.First_Name, E.Last_Name, E.Language FROM Employees AS E
```

I've tried entering in a WHERE clause but that doesn't seem to work.

Please note that I'm fairly new to SQL and the more you dumb it down, the better I understand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common practice to use a "lookup" table of languages, with two fields (LanguageID (primary Key, autonumber) and LanguageName (text)). This would allow you to easily expand the data to include as many languages as you need. In order to display the information required, your SQL would look like:

```
SELECT E.EmployeeID, E.FirstName, E.LastName, L.LanguageName
FROM Employees AS E INNER JOIN Languages AS L ON L.LanguageID=E.Language
```

Regards,

Answer (score -1):

That should be straight forward with a CASE statement, I am assuming you are using SQL Server. Try something like this

`SELECT E.employee_ID, E.First_Name, E.Last_Name, CASE E.Language WHEN 1 THEN 'English' WHEN 2 THEN 'French' END as Language FROM Employees AS E`

Comment: You can additionally have a catch all for anything that doesn't match a 1 or 2, using the ELSE keyword.

Comment: This is T-SQL, Not usable in Access SQL.

Comment: I think you are right, I guess you can use IIF keyword or a SWITCH statement in Access SQL.